# Android NDK - implement callback/listener code

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My JNI folder contains the following CPP file:

```
class RdNative : public IRdListener {
  virtual void screenChanged() {
       LOGI("RdNative :: screenChanged()");
   }

  static jboolean _init (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    ...
  }
...
}
```

`screenChanged()` shall be called when the screen changes.

In my Android project, I have created RdNative.java in order to call the static native functions in the CPP file.

```
public class RdNative {
  {
     System.loadLibrary("testapp");
  }

  public native boolean init();
  ...
}
```

When my app launches, I start a service that initiates an `RdNative` object. However, I noticed that the callback method in the cpp FILE `screenChanged()` is not being called.

Any idea why?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that calls `screenChanged`.

Comment: @Michael this is a callback by the interface IRdListener which is part of a third party library.